# How to show pagination series with dot in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

code:

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attandance"; 
    $retval1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($retval1);  
    $total_records = $row[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);    
    echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page)."' class='button'>Previous</a></li>"; 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
        echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a></li>";
    echo "</ul>";                   
?>
```

I have create a pagination in php  now its work fine but pagination series look like previous 1234567891011121314151617181920 next like this but I want like 
Previous 1 2 3 4 5 . . . . 20 next. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here is some helpful code for you, please check this.

```
<?php
// Please place your select query over here.
// $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attandance"; 
// $retval1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
// $row = mysqli_fetch_row($retval1);  
// $total_records = $row[0];

$page = ((isset($_GET['page'])) && ($_GET['page'] != ''))? $_GET['page'] : 1;
echo "You are on Page: ".$page;
$limit = 5; // I'm all this as static, please change it
$total_records = 34; // I'm all this as static, please change it to `$row[0]`

$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);    
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
if ($page > 1)
echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page - 1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a></li>"; 

$show = 0;
for ($i = $page; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
  $show++;
  if ($page == $i) 
    echo "<li class='active'>".$i."</li>";
  else if (($show < 5) || ($total_pages == $i))
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
  else
    echo "<li class='dot'>.</li>";
}

if ($total_pages > $page)
echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=".($page + 1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";                   
?>
```

If you need some CSS, try using:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}

li.active {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li.dot {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```